# input capture file reduce and convert issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, html-input

I tried to Html5 input capture from camera(Samsung Tab s7) and then resize(my main goal this point is reducing image size) and than upload post method via my controller. But when I upload, my file recognized .bin and save like this. Icouldnt save jpeg. How can I solve it?

**HTML** :

```
 <input type="file" id="captureImageInput" style="display:none;" accept="image/*" capture>
```

**JS :**

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('captureImageInput');
 fileInput.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if (e.target.files.length == 0) {
            // No file captured, ignore
            return;
        }
    else{
        var imageFile = e.target.files[0];
        //--resize image START

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var img1 = document.createElement("img");
        img1.setAttribute('src', imageFile); 
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
        var width = img1.width;
        var height = img1.height;

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        }
        else if (width == 0 && height == 0)
        {
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        } 
        else {
            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
       
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, width, height);

        var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        var blobBin = atob(dataurl.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
            array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        var resizedFileBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
   
        //--resize image END
        
         var fullFileName = serialNo + "-" + stockNo;

         var fileImage = new File([resizedFileBlob], fullFileName);

         var myFormData = new FormData();
         myFormData.append('FormFile', fileImage);

          $.ajax({
          //POST OPERATION TO CONTROLLER
          });

     }

  });
```

**Controller side:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SavePhysicalPath(FileModel myFormData) 
 { 
   //update physical path operatıons..
 }
```

**FileModel class:**

```
 public class FileModel
    {
        public string FileFolderPath { get; set; }
        public string Files { get; set; }
        public IFormFile[] FormFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I think the issue is related you have create a new file by using this line  `var fileImage = new File([resizedFileBlob], fullFileName);`.

I suggest you could remove this line and directly use the `resizedFileBlob`  as the parameter and pass to backend.

I have create a test demo as below and you could refer to it.

Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {

            // set size proportional to image
            canvas.height = canvas.width * (img.height / img.width);

            // step 1 - resize to 50%
            var oc = document.createElement('canvas'),
                octx = oc.getContext('2d');

            oc.width = img.width * 0.5;
            oc.height = img.height * 0.5;
            octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);

            // step 2
            octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5);

            // step 3, resize to final size
            ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5,
                0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);




        }
        img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/SHo6Fub.jpg";

        var cav = document.getElementById("canvas");
        const file = dataURLtoBlob(cav.toDataURL());
        var fileImage = new File([file], "test");
        const fd = new FormData;

        fd.append('image', fileImage);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/Foo',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        });

    });


    function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
        let array, binary, i, len;
        binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
        array = [];
        i = 0;
        len = binary.length;
        while (i < len) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
            type: 'image/png'
        });
    };

</script>
```

View:

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/SHo6Fub.jpg" width="300" height="234">
<canvas id="canvas" width=300></canvas>
```

Result:

[image]